# Как передать значение radio или checkbox в MySQL

Tags: checkbox, form, php, mysql

```
   <form method='post' action='vibstuttabl.php'>
ФИО студента:<input type='text' name='fio' /></br>
Номер группы:<input type='text' name='group' /></br>
Контакт старосты:<input type='text' name='inst' /></br>

<td>Староста?Да:***<input type="checkbox" name="checks"  value="Староста"/>***

<input type='submit' name='addinfogroup' value='Добавить студента' />
</td>
</form>
```

php обрабртчик выдает такую ошибку:

> Undefined index: checks in C:\Apache2.2\htdocs\g\vibstuttabl.php on line 6
> Array ( [fio] => Швайка [group] => 3412 [inst] => 13123 [addinfogroup] => Добавить студента ) Запрос успешно обработан
> и вот его код

```
<?php
include 'db.php';
$prst=0;
$fio_stud = $_POST['fio'];
$g=$_POST['group'];
$prst=$_POST['checks'];
$ist=$_POST['inst'];

if(isset($_POST['addinfogroup']))
{
$dobavka=mysql_query("INSERT INTO studenti(fio_student,Group,pr_st,info_st) VALUES('$fio_stud','$g,'$prst','$ist')");
        print_r($_POST);
    echo "Запрос успешно обработан"; exit;
}
    ?>
```

Comment: ваш код подвержен sql injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(isset($_POST['addinfogroup']))
```

Меняй на

```
if ($_POST['submit' ]== 'send_msg')
```

А это меняй на

ОТКЛЮЧАТЬ НОТИСЫ ГЛУПО!!! Нотис ошибка на логику!!! а их не должно быть!!!

```
<input type='submit' name='send_msg' value='Добавить студента' />
```

Comment: ноотис? как правильно было бы?

Comment: см выше отредачил

$prst=0;

$prst=$_POST['checks'];

!!! через if пускай!

Comment: ошибка осталась  со строкой  $prst=$_POST['checks'];
и добавилась с измененной вашей стройкой if ($_POST['submit' ]== 'send_msg')  
вот ошибки=(  собственно ошибка осталась
Notice: Undefined index: checks in C:\Apache2.2\htdocs\g\vibstuttabl.php on line 6

Notice: Undefined index: submit in C:\Apache2.2\htdocs\g\vibstuttabl.php on line 9

Comment: я же написал что логика не правильная!
$prst=0;

$prst=$_POST['checks'];

сначала 0 потом через пост берется, код за вас никто писать не будет и кто минусанул???

Answer (score 0):

"Notice" насколько я помню не ошибка, а предупреждение, сам код исполняется корректно, я проверял. Вероятнее всего вы галка у вас в чекбоксе не установлена, и данный элемент массива просто пустой. В файле-приемнике просто проверяйте значение таких элементов.
Реакцию на Notice можно отключить в php.ini

Comment: Реакцию можно отключить, но скрывать её - это не решение.

Comment: Все зависит от момента использования скрипта.
Вот выдержка из мануала:
В PHP 4 и PHP 5 значение по умолчанию E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE. В этом режиме ошибки уровня E_NOTICE не показываются. Однако, они могут потребоваться во время разработки скрипта.